# Firebase real time data listener

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question about Firebase Database. After data has been changed , does the listener give you whole data again or just the recently added data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) says:

> You can use the onDataChange() method to read a static snapshot of the
>   contents at a given path, as they existed at the time of the event.
>   This method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again
>   every time the data, including children, changes. The event callback
>   is passed a snapshot containing **all data** at that location, including
>   child data. If there is no data, the snapshot returned is null.

So **also the unchanged parts** of the data are returned.

This just means that you should use as specific and narrowed-down listeners as possible, as the documentation also suggests:

> Important: The onDataChange() method is called every time data is
>   changed at the specified database reference, including changes to
>   children. To limit the size of your snapshots, attach only at the
>   highest level needed for watching changes. For example, attaching a
>   listener to the root of your database is not recommended.